# Do we need to synchronize local object variable in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have one function which is called in multi-threaded environment. It has one locally created object. Do we need to synchronize local object variable?

e.g.

```
void myFun() {

  SomeClass obj = SomeClass();

  // This object is then passed to some other method.

}
```

Do we need to get mutex lock on above locally created object (i.e. obj)? to make it work properly in multi threaded environment.

}

Comment: Objects created on stack (i.e. locally created object) doesn't require locking. Each thread calling the function will have its own separate copy of the object.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the object is global or local. All that matters is that if you access an object from different threads and at least some of these accesses could modify the object, then you must synchronize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is created on the stack of the current thread. Unless you store a pointer or reference to it somewhere else, no other thread can even see it.

Comment: it also depends if the object accesses some shared resources. But then I guess it's the object's responsibility to behave in a multithreaded environment, i.e. be thread safe.

Comment: @EJP thanks for answer, What is I'm creating above object on HEAP? i.e. Simple *sPtr = new Simple(). Is this case also we don't need synchronization?

Comment: @ProAccount Of course not. Multiple threads can see it, if you pass the pointer around.